# Running app on MacOSX Mountain Lion: Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 13

Tags: macos, launchd

I tried to run an app on my mac but it quickly closes, I've checked the Quarantine flag but that was not the problem, I checked Console and here's the error information:

```
9/24/12 1:44:19.343 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[150]: ([0x0-0x330330].com.krill.CodeRunner[5405]) Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 13
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `errno` 13 would be `EACCESS` (permission denied).

Comment: @lanzz do you have a link for the source of the errno explanation?

Comment: http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/2/errno/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thanks to lanzz

I found out that the problem is permissions.

I used **chmod +x** to set the executable app under **MacOS** folder of the .app to make it executable and the problem is fixed.

Comment: This worked beautifully. I also ran into this issue with Minecraft and Slender: The Eight Pages. using `chmod u+x <Application.app>/Contents/MacOS/<application binary>` fixed the problem in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

If `chmod` doesn't work for you:

I was getting the same error with an .app file extracted from a zip but the `chmod` solution didn't help.  I eventually found [this page](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4543912?start=0&tstart=0) which suggested re-extracting the file from the original zip using the Archive Utility.  This worked for my case.

(I had extracted it using 7-Zip on a PC and picked it up on the Mac via DropBox which presumably mangled the permissions in some manner.)